# WHere else timeout settings may exist?

Tags: php, laravel, http, timeout, server-configuration

I'm trying to increase timeout settings on my dev server, but for some reason it keep sends 504 gateway timeout after 30sec error despite all the settings I've done.

What I've already done:

- set php ini "max_input_time", "max_input_time" and "request_terminate_timeout" to 60 (and checked that all other timeout settings are greater than 60s). then checked phpinfo to assure that canges have been applied.
- set nginx's "send_timeout", "fastcgi_connect_timeout" and "proxy_connect_timeout" to 60s (and checked that all other timeout settings are greater than 60s)
- called set_time_limit(0) in my php script
- rebooted server

But it still breakes connection after 30sec..

So, what may I miss? Where else timeout settings may exist? Where to dig?
Is there a way to figure out what particular service causes timeout?

My platform is:

- hestiacp control panel (nginx+apache+php 8.2+mariadb)
- laravel 9 framework

Btw, long jobs works well (managed by artisan:work under "supervisor"), without any timeout issues. Timeout occurs only when long query is run by http get/post request.

Comment: have you ping the sv?